# Laravel 5 Using orderBy() with Models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

So I can't for the life of me figure out why I can't use orderBy. I'm getting the error:

> **Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy()**

Here is my code:

```
Route::get('/teams', function(){
$page = 'Teams';
$teams = App\Team::all()->orderBy('teamFirstName')->get();
return view('teams')->with('page', $page)->with('allTeams', $teams);
});
```

I have tried removing the `->get();` I have tried using just `Team::all`. I'm using a Laravel cheat sheet and I seem to be following the Model syntax. I have also double checked that it is the right column name in my DB and have even tried using just id.

If I remove the `->orderBy()` the query works fine and I can get all of the teams. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because `all()` returns a `Collection` which does not have an `orderBy` method (though it does have a `sortBy` method which you could use).  The following is a bit simpler though and should perform better.

```
$teams = App\Team::orderBy('teamFirstName')->get();
```

Once you call `all()`, the query is ran and results are fetched and any ordering done after this would be done by PHP.  It's usually best to let the database handle the ordering though so use `orderBy()` first before fetching the results with `get()`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
$teams = App\Team::all()->orderBy('teamFirstName')->get();
```

Need to be:

```
$teams = App\Team::orderBy('teamFirstName')->get();
```

### Note:

user3158900 has a good explanation.